# Modifying a Cookie's Value in a HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httphandler

I've got a cookie that I'm using to persist a user's userid but I'm having a hard time replacing it with a new value. According to MSDN, I should be able to simply overwrite the value, but it hasn't been working. I'm doing the login logic in a handler and passing the user on to a new webpage if they succeed.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    User user = User.FindByUsernameAndPassword(
        context.Request.Form["username"],
        context.Request.Form["password"]);

    context.Response.Cookies["user_id"].Value = user.ID.ToString();

    context.Response.Redirect("/profile", true);
}
```

The first time I log in it works well, but if I try to overwrite my current cookie by hitting the handler with a new user id, it doesn't change the cookie value and I continue to be logged in as the user I was when I hit it.

Other pages use the cookie to log in, but because the user id isn't changing it doesn't change the logged in user.

```
public User User { get; set; }

public override void Page_Load()
{
    this.User = User.Find(int.Parse(Request.Cookies["user_id"].Value));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `.Value`

```
context.Response.Cookies["user_id"].Value = user.ID.ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a typo. The code won't even compile if you do it without the `.Value`.

Comment: do we need to check if cookie exist before modifying its value,In other words will it error if cookie doesnt exist and we try to modify the value of a cookie which does not exist ?

Comment: yes, if the cookie is null, you can't access its Value property

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx), you have write a new cookie with the same name, not just modify it:

> **Modifying and Deleting Cookies**
>
> You cannot directly modify a cookie.
>   Instead, changing a cookie consists of
>   creating a new cookie with new values
>   and then sending the cookie to the
>   browser to overwrite the old version
>   on the client. The following code
>   example shows how you can change the
>   value of a cookie that stores a count
>   of the user's visits to the site:

```
int counter;
if (Request.Cookies["counter"] == null)
    counter = 0;
else
{
    counter = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["counter"].Value);
}
counter++;

Response.Cookies["counter"].Value = counter.ToString();
Response.Cookies["counter"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

I'd agree with the first post about adding the .Value property and then maybe add the .Expires as well and see what happens.

Comment: do we need to check if cookie exist before modifying its value,In other words will it error if cookie doesnt exist and we try to modify the value of a cookie which does not exist ?